# How to delete BottomNavigationView paddings?

Tags: android, width, reduce, bottomnavigationview

Everything is normal BottomNavigationView width until when i was added 2 items for menu like this;

```
<item android:id="@+id/menuMainButon"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="MainPage"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

</item>

<item android:id="@+id/menuMessage"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="Message"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_message"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

</item>
```

then when i am giving app:menu="@menu/menu_main" property to BottomNavigationView like this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />
```

BottomNavigationView is reduce own width. 
What can i do for removing padding both sides?(left-right)

Answer (score 2):

for me it was enough to add a Background color to the BottomNavigationView so the padding is not seen anymore.

```
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
```